# SQLiteOpenHelper Query - How to show the SQL-Statment

Tags: java, android, sqliteopenhelper, sqlcipher

I'd like to know if it's possible to see the SQL-Statment which the SQLiteOpenHelper generates. Here's some Sample-Code:

```
    String selection = "USER_LOGIN=?";
    String[] sectionArgument = new String[]{"username"};
    String[] columns = new String[]{"USER_LOGIN", "USER_PASS"};

    Cursor c = mDatabase.query("ACCOUNT_TABLE", columns, selection, sectionArgument, null, null, null);
```

Now how is it possible to see the generated SQL-Statment form the `query-Method`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the queries that are issued to a SQLCipher database, please refer to the [`PRAGMA cipher_profile`](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/#cipher_profile) command which will allow you to capture both the queries and their respective execution time in milliseconds.